# Can PHP work with all flavours of SQL?

Tags: php, sql

I have always worked with mySQL, but have recently recieved a spec for a contract that requires the site to be build in ASP.net in order to read and write data from their SQL database.

Do I have to do this? or is this misinformation? Can I still work in PHP and have access to the SQL database?

Comment: The answer is 'Yes it can' (you already have several answers to that effect), but bear in mind if you're used to working with MySQL that MS-SQL has some significant language differences to MySQL, so you may have to adapt your queries to suit the different dialect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP supports all the major SQL databases. See [this list](http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.database.php).

Answer (score 0):

mySQL is not the same as SQL. mySQL is a type of an SQL database.
There isn't a database type created that can't be accessed by php.. at least none that I have knowledge of.

Answer (score 0):

yes use PHP-Driver :

this http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/PHP-Driver.aspx

documentation :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296221.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use php but you should not as the spec is requiring something different. Customers tend to be unhappy when you arbitrarily ignore thier requirements because you don't like what they want. Perhaps they will be supporting the product with developers who are .net developers.

I woulod hold you in breach of contract if I requested a .net product and you delivered a php product.